# Dynamic throttling of an ActiveMQ message queue with Camel

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I am an ActiveMQ / Camel noob with a specific scenario in mind, I wonder firstly if it is possible and secondly whether someone might provide a little direction.

Basically I need to perform dynamic throttling off the queue. I.E the ability to set **at runtime** the rate a particular group of messages will be consumed from the queue.

So I might, for example, add a group of messages that are to be consumed at 10 per second, another group which should be consumed at 1 per second and so forth.

I know the basics of setting up routes in camel and message grouping onto the queue etc, but just can't figure this out from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah looks like you are looking for broker side throtteling to avoid consumers to block.

Have you raised your request at the ActiveMQ user/dev forum?

Answer (score 4):

You could just use Camel's existing [throttler](http://activemq.apache.org/camel/throttler.html) then using a different queue for each type of messages where you need to configure a different throttle rate?

e.g.

```
from("activemq:Queue1.Input").
    throttle(20).
    to("activemq:Queue1.Output");  
from("activemq:Queue2.Input").
    throttle(5).
    to("activemq:Queue2.Output");
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you add a RFE in the Apache Camel JIRA?

What are your logic for determining the rate for a given group of messages?

If different group of messages passes throughout the same throttler it can get complex. It kinda need discriminator to determine any Message which group it belongs to and thus which rate is should pass the throttler with.

If you take some time to fill in your use case and log the RFE then I am sure the Camel community, developers can help.

You can try to implement it yourself. Basically anything is a Processor, so you can do a from("activemq:queue:foo").process(myOwnThrottler).to("bean:handleMessage");

You can extend some of the classes in Camel:
- DelegateProcessor
- DelayProcessorSupport
- Throttler

---

Claus Ibsen
Apache Camel Committer

Open Source Integration: http://fusesource.com
Blog: http://davsclaus.blogspot.com/

Comment: Just bought a EAP copy of your book "Camel in Action" Claus. It is excellent and I can definitely recommend it for anyone else getting to grips with, or wanting to learn more about Camel. Very in-depth stuff.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll lay out the scenario in a bit more detail and highlight the main blocker as far as I can tell.

I have 2 groups of messages (in reality the scale with be much larger), each with a different throttling requirement - Let's say, I specify this in the message header as flowRate and flowTime.

- Group 1: FlowRate = 1; flowTime = 60 (1 per minute)
- Group 2: FlowRate = 1; flowTime = 1
  (1 per second)

I implement a Processor as per [Claus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56384/claus-ibsen) which examines the header fields and uses them as delayer input.

I add 20000 messages from group 1 and 20000 from group 2

Because the throttler is consumer side, the delayer activated by group 1 will cause it to become slow by quickly filling its input buffer and group 2 messages will then become stuck...even if I use multiple queues as per [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12235/james-strachan).

I realise that I can group the message using the JMXGroupID header and implement multiple consumers, but don't think that would scale to the requirement for accommodating *n* groups.

What I was wondering, basically, is if there is any way to do broker, rather than consumer side throttling, or some other solution, whereby the consumer can throttle without ultimately blocking.

Hope I've explained myself clearly and thanks for the suggestions so far.